# Rest API - Put or Patch

Tags: rest, powershell

I am trying to use the Rest API in order to change values in a TFS2017 build using powershell. I have it working in Postman but I'm using the PUT method which requires you to have every value specified in order to update the build.

I'm trying to find a solution that will update one variable and everything else stay the same. I'm not sure that my endpoint is correct. This is what I have

```
http://MyTFS:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Project/_apis/build/definitions/MyBuildID?api-version=3.0
```

When I run GET on this, I have:

```
*A bunch of text*
    "variables": {
        "system.debug": {
            "value": "false",
            "allowOverride": true
        },
        "BuildVersion": {
            "value": "ValueIWantToChange"
        }
    },
*A bunch of text*
```

I've successfully used the put method and don't mind using it so long as the amount of variables is not excessive. I've attempted to use the Patch method  but it is not supported.

The only thing I want to change is the build version. I need a simple request to update that value. This is my first time using REST API calls so I'm sorry if this is overly simple.

**Edit:** When I run patch, I just get  "The requested resource does not support http method 'PATCH'". Maybe I'm going wrong here? My json body looks like this for the request:

```
{
    "Variables":
    {
        "BuildVersion": 
        {
            "value": "ValueToChangeTo"
        }
    }
}
```

I think it would also be good to mention that when I set up Powershell to run the PUT command I get the same error as well. PUT works properly in Postman so I don't see what the issue is.

Comment: What error are you getting back on the PATCH through Powershell?

Comment: I edited my question above :)

Comment: Looking at the [api documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/definitions/update%20definition?view=vsts-rest-4.1)  it does not appear that it is possible to PATCH your build definitions, only PUT at the moment. I tried it on our TFS 2018 instance using API version 3.0,  4.1-preview.1 (I get a 405 Method not allowed error) and 5.0-preview-1 (the endpoint does not exist in that version) I look forward to seeing what solutions are put forward.

Comment: I'm confused -- the error says "The requested resource does not support http method 'PATCH'" but you say that you can PATCH using Postman?

Comment: No, I can use PUT successfully in Postman. I have tried PATCH and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Self describing APIs are great -- and informative error messages are even better!  Looks like you answered your own question with the error message:

```
"The requested resource does not support http method 'PATCH'"
```

Looks like it simply doesn't support PATCH (which is pretty common).